# How to get data from two table using AngularJs from Mysql DB

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs

I want to fetch data from two different tables from mysql using Angular Js. My tables are shown below:

Comment

```
ID,User_id,Comment
```

User

```
Id,Name,Email,Password
```

I want to display data with angluarJs in this format:

```
Username : comments
```

Answer (score 0):

To get all comments you want to run the following statement:

```
SELECT Name AS Username, Comment
FROM user, comments
WHERE user.id = comments.user_id
```

This is combining the two tables and matching the user_id from the comments table with the id from the users table.

Answer (score 0):

In general, it's a bad practice to query databases directly using Angular. The recommended way of doing this is to expose the data via (RESTful) API's which in turn, perform the queries at the back-end and return the data in some format (e.g., JSON) which Angular can then consume.